# Joining matrices based on relation in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices A and B. A is the dataset and B is info about classes which instances(rows) of A belong to.
I need to add the class info to the matrix A, and I don't know how, which function to use?
Matrix examples:

```
A = [A a v c
     B a d c
     B s x d
     C s c s]
B = [A 0
     B 1
     C 0]
```

And i need:

```
A = [A a v c 0
     B a d c 1
     B s x d 1
     C s c s 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(A, lookup(A, B))
```

Which gives:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] "A"  "a"  "v"  "c"  "0" 
# [2,] "B"  "a"  "d"  "c"  "1" 
# [3,] "B"  "s"  "x"  "d"  "1" 
# [4,] "C"  "s"  "c"  "s"  "0"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by calling `match` to determine the row of B corresponding to each row of A:

```
cbind(A, B[match(A[,1], B[,1]),2])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,] "A"  "a"  "v"  "c"  "0" 
# [2,] "B"  "a"  "d"  "c"  "1" 
# [3,] "B"  "s"  "x"  "d"  "1" 
# [4,] "C"  "s"  "c"  "s"  "0"
```

Data:

```
A <- matrix(c("A", "B", "B", "C", "a", "a", "s", "s", "v", "d", "x", "c", "c", "c", "d", "s"), nrow=4)
B <- matrix(c("A", "B", "C", 0, 1, 0), nrow=3)
```